# Report Builder 3.0 Date Prompt + / - 14 days

Tags: reportbuilder3.0

I have a report where the users selects the date in the prompt.  I need to change the code so the report selects data 14 days before and 14 days after the selected date.

This is why I currently have and it runs:

cast(pymt_dt as date format 'MM/DD/YYYY') = ?

I'm trying to change it to between but it throws an error message when it runs.  This is what I changed it to:

cast(pymt_dt as date format 'MM/DD/YYYY') between (? - 14) and (? + 14)

I'm sure the syntax is wrong but not sure how to correct it.  The question marks represent the value from the date prompt.  The Date Prompt value is date / time.

Thanks for the help....

Answer (score 0):

I would use `DateAdd()`. So where you have `(? - 14) and (? + 14)` it'd be `DateAdd(d, -14, ?) And DateAdd(d, 14, ?)`

DateAdd() pretty self explanatory - the first parameter defines an interval, the second the amount of interval you want to add and the last the date you want to add it to, so this is add 14/-14 days to ?

Hope that helps.

Comment: .........Thanks for the info.  I ended up using "interval" to make it work.  Thanks for your suggestion